# Force to email with different subjet be same conversation

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2013

I use "arrange by date (conversation)" in outlook to group all of the emails in a particular thread

The question I have is has anyone figured out how to group two different conversation threads in to one group?

For example, a client will send an email to me with the subject of "We need two spare parts A", and as long as we reply back and forth to the same email the conversation is all grouped into one group with the same subject. But if they send me another email with the subject "Here is information about the address", it will start another conversation group, and I cannot figure out how to link it back to the original conversation.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: question does not belong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I modify conversationTopic so emails with different subjects are put in the same thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806882/how-can-i-modify-conversationtopic-so-emails-with-different-subjects-are-put-in)

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue..but i haven't found a solution to it. This link [here](http://www.microsofttraining.net/article-1462-how-use-conversations-settings-outlook-2010.html) says that this is by design.