# Obtain "sender" and "emailbody" properties

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

***Background***

I scan the inbox in Outlook and report the results to a Excel spreadsheet based on the Title of the email. I will use the same example as in Microsoft office keyword and will say "Office".

IE: Office: Problem with Laptop.
I need to get the user name or email address that sent the mail and probably some keywords in the body of the email itself.

I found the way to iterate through the items that have this keyword only by using tables and rows.

***Problem***

I have not been able to find a way to cast the row.item from the table to an email nor to obtain "sender" or "emailbody" properties.

***Code***

You need to add Outlook reference

```
Option Base 1
Sub Outlook_ScanForEmails()
Const TxtTag  As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
Const TxtWordSubject As String = "Office:"
Dim OutTable As Outlook.Table
Dim OutRow As Outlook.Row
Dim OutEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application: Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim CounterEmails As Long
Dim TotalEmails As Long
Dim TxtFilter As String: TxtFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & TxtTag & "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch '" & TxtWordSubject & "'"
Dim TxtCourse As String
Dim DteReport As Date
Set OutTable = OutApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).GetTable(TxtFilter)
    TotalEmails = OutTable.GetRowCount
    For CounterEmails = 1 To TotalEmails
    Set OutRow = OutTable.GetNextRow
    DteReport = OutRow("LastModificationTime")
    TxtCourse = OutRow("Subject")
    TxtCourse = Right(TxtCourse, Len(TxtCourse) - Len(TxtWordSubject))
    Next CounterEmails

End Sub
```

***Further thoughts***

I would prefer to not iterate through each email since the table narrows the process to iterating only the row items I need.

Comment: `If you require a writeable object from the Table row, obtain the Entry ID for that row from the default EntryID column in the Table and then use the GetItemFromID method of the NameSpace object to obtain a full item, such as a MailItem or ContactItem, that supports read-write operations.` from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/table-object-outlook

Comment: Thanks @Sorceri ! However, I cannot find the way to do that approach. I have tried this `IDNumber = OutRow.Parent.Columns.Item(1)` and `Set OutEmail = OutApp.Session.GetItemFromID(OutRow("Subject"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment you can get a mail item from the entryID column of the table.  Here is an example of how to accomplish this.

```
Option Base 1
Sub Outlook_ScanForEmails()
Const TxtTag  As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
Const TxtWordSubject As String = "Office:"
Dim OutTable As Outlook.Table
Dim OutRow As Outlook.Row
Dim OutEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application: Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim CounterEmails As Long
Dim TotalEmails As Long
Dim TxtFilter As String: TxtFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & TxtTag & "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch '" & TxtWordSubject & "'"
Dim TxtCourse As String
Dim DteReport As Date

Set OutTable = OutApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).GetTable()
    TotalEmails = OutTable.GetRowCount
    For CounterEmails = 1 To TotalEmails
    Set OutRow = OutTable.GetNextRow
    DteReport = OutRow("LastModificationTime")
    TxtCourse = OutRow("Subject")
    'Define a string for the EntryId
    Dim entryID As String
    'get EntrId
    entryID = OutRow("EntryID")
    'define a MailItem
    Dim mi As MailItem
    'Get the MailItem from the ID
    Set mi = OutApp.Session.GetItemFromID(entryID)
    'do something with the mail item
    TxtCourse = Right(TxtCourse, Len(TxtCourse) - Len(TxtWordSubject))
    Next CounterEmails

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting, I was so lost in trying to call it as a either function or from the columns.

Answer (score 1):

To extract outlook Emails to excel use the following code in an excel file with reference Microsoft Outlook View Control and MS Outlook 16.0 Object library.

Code:

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Mail")
Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).GetTable(TxtFilter)    
i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
'here you can update the condition to which it should be extracted

    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime > ws.Range("D" & i).Value And OutlookMail.Subject <> ws.Range("B" & i).Value Then 
            ws.Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        ws.Range("C1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        ws.Range("D1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        ws.Range("E1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        ws.Range("F1").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, however, you are setting a folder from a table, hence there is an error while trying to run it

Comment: Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox), here it refers to the folder Inbox where as you can alter your target folder as your wish like eg: Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("new folder") the Emails inside folder "new folder" get extracted.