# Outlook VBA script to change subject of email working, but change not reflected in 'inbox' window

Tags: vba, outlook

I  have an Outlook VBA script that prompts me for an old word and a new word and then changes 'old word' to 'new word' for all selected emails:

```
Public Sub replaceWords()
    Dim item As Outlook.mailItem

    oldWord = InputBox("Please enter a word to replace. Remebver to include spaces. Enter 'quit' to exit")
    If oldWord = "quit" Then Exit Sub
    newWord = InputBox("and now the word you'd like to replace it with")
    Set oldWordRegex = New RegExp
    With oldWordRegex
        .Pattern = oldWord
        .Global = True
    End With

    For Each item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
            'remove the "Issued at..." from the end of the subject and a
            item.Subject = oldWordRegex.Replace(item.Subject, newWord)
            item.Save
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

As far as I can tell this is working fine, except that the change to the subject is not reflected in the main 'Inbox' window. to demonstrate, I sent myself en emails with the subject "This little piggy went to market" and then ran my macro and changed 'piggy' to 'froggy'. Result show below:

[image: Email example]

Question: Does Outlook have to rebuild the Inbox list from the subjects of the emails in the inbox and if so, can you force it to do this?

Comment: I think that this is because what your actually looking at is a "conversation topic" rather than the actual subject, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806882/how-can-i-modify-conversationtopic-so-emails-with-different-subjects-are-put-in

Comment: Thanks Alex  - that appears be it. If you make this an answer, ill upvote and accept it.