# Count original emails

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to count emails in Outlook over a specific timeframe, from Excel. I hardcoded that timeframe for now. That part seems to work, at least the count is correct.

I need the count for new emails. It is counting every email, rather than just the originals.

I looked at `.GetConversation` and then read that `conversationID` changes with each email, so the original has 44 characters. I thought that would be a good way to filter, but I do not understand what is in that property because it's not working.

It works until it tries to filter by the conversation ID.

```vb
Sub cntEmail()
'I WILL NEVER COUNT EMAILS AGAIN, dangit
    Dim ns As Namespace: Set ns = GetNamespace(Type:="MAPI")
    Dim fldr As Folder, fldrDone As Outlook.Folder
    Dim inboxItems As Items, doneItems As Items, sFilter As String
    
    Set fldr = ns.Folders("Call Center").Folders("Inbox")
    Set fldrDone = ns.Folders("Call Center").Folders("DONE")
    Set inboxItems = fldr.Items
    Set doneItems = fldrDone.Items
    sFilter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" & Format("1/13/2023 17:00", "ddddd h:mm AMPM") & "' AND [LastModificationTime] < '" & Format("1/20/2023 16:59", "ddddd h:mm AMPM") & "'"
    Set inboxItems = inboxItems.Restrict(sFilter)
    Set doneItems = doneItems.Restrict(sFilter)
    
    Debug.Print "Total Inbox Count: " & inboxItems.Count
    Debug.Print "Total Done Count: " & doneItems.Count
    
    'Everything above this comment works

    Set inboxItems = inboxItems.Restrict("[ConversationID] < 45")
    Set doneItems = doneItems.Restrict("[ConversationID] < 45")
    
    Debug.Print "Total Inbox Count: " & inboxItems.Count
    Debug.Print "Total Done Count: " & doneItems.Count

    Set fldr = Nothing
    Set fldrDone = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**ConversationID**

From what I understand `ConversationID` is a property that will have the same value for all the mailItems that belong to the same conversation (more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/categories-and-conversations/managing-outlook-items-as-conversations)).

This means that if you reply to an email and the person replies to your reply, the second email you receive from them should have the same `ConversationID`.

I'm assuming that when you say that you want to count "original emails", you mean that you want to avoid counting the second email as it's part of the conversation initiated by the first (original) email.

So basically, you want to count how many unique values of ConversationID you have among your mailItems.

I haven't used `.Restrict`, so I'm not sure if you can use it for this purpose, but there are ways to get the total count of unique values for `ConversationID` by looping on the `MailItems` and counting the unique values.

---

**Option 1: Using a Collection**

One way to do it would be to use a collection. Since a collection can't contain two elements with the same key, we can use it to count the number of unique values.

For example:

```vb
    Dim UniqueConversations As New Collection
    
    Dim inboxItem As MailItem
    For Each inboxItem In inboxItems
        On Error Resume Next
            'This line will return an error when the key already matches an item in the collection
            'and the item won't be added to the collection.
            UniqueConversations.Add 1, inboxItem.ConversationID
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next inboxItem

    Debug.Print "Total Inbox Count: " & UniqueConversations.Count
```

---

**Option 2: Using a Dictionary**

The dictionary solution is a little more elegant as we don't need to use `On error` statements.

The reason why we don't get an error when we use a dictionary is that we'll just overwrite the stored value when the key already exists in the dictionary.

For example:

```vb
    'Make sure to include Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library or use the drop-in replacement VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary on Mac
    Dim dict As Dictionary
    Set dict = New Dictionary
    
    Dim inboxItem As MailItem
    For Each inboxItem In inboxItems
        dict.Item(inboxItem.ConversationID) = 1
    Next inboxItem
    
    Debug.Print "Total Inbox Count: " & dict.Count
```

If you have a lot of emails, the dictionary approach is usually faster, but I haven't noticed a big difference for the small tests I've done.

Comment: I tried both options and they helped.  Each paired down the count a little, but there are still too many there.  The count beforehand is 163.  It should be 116.  It came back with 149.

Comment: @Iakona, how do you know the right amount that it should be exactly?

Comment: I manually counted them.  I had to know the number I was shooting for.  I just dont want to have to do that every danged week.

Comment: And let me clarify, just in case I am misunderstanding what I'm counting.  I originally counted and got 160-something.  The person showing me how she does it got the smaller number.  We compared setups and I had every email showing up separately.  We changed my view of the inbox from Single to Compact and I got the same number she had.  I am assuming the same is the problem with the automated counting, but there could be something else I do not even know exists.

Comment: Never loop through all items in a folder. Some folders can contains thousands of messages.

Comment: @Iakona, I'm not sure, but maybe this is due to the difference between  `ConversationID`  and `ConversationTopic` ? Potentially related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806882/how-can-i-modify-conversationtopic-so-emails-with-different-subjects-are-put-in)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, that's a fair disclaimer, but here a time filter was already applied, so I think a loop could be reasonable here provided that the time range is small.

Comment: @DecimalTurn - the two conditions (on PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX  and LastModificationTime) can be combined into a single query.

Comment: Dmitry's is streamlined, but it does not address my original question.  I thank you for trying to address my query, Decimal, especially with the explanations.  Only way I'll leave here with not just an answer, but the knowledge to avoid questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a restriction on property length like `[ConversationID] < 45` (you can in Extended MAPI, but it is only available from C++ or Delphi). Try to create a restriction on `PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX` MAPI property being an empty string. On replies it is `"RE"` and `"FW"` on forwards.

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003D001F" = ''
```

in your code:

```
Set inboxItems = inboxItems.Restrict("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003D001F"" = ''")
Set doneItems = doneItems.Restrict("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x003D001F"" = ''")
```